# How to check if the content of the Target cell is deleted in a Worksheet_Change Event

Tags: excel, vba

I want to either delete the validation of a cell or set an empty validation if the Target of Worksheet_Change is deleted.

The Target cell is a merged cell which also has a `xlValidateList`. If I choose one of the values, my code runs ok, but when I delete the content of this cell, it doesn't change the validation of the other cell.

I think it comes from the merging of the cells or because it has a `xlValidateList`

I tried to check `IsEmpty(Target)` but its always FALSE, even if I delete the content of the Target cell

My code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim lengthFromCell As range
Dim lengthToCell As range

' only execute when on column F and
If Target.Column <> 6 Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Set lengthFromCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
Set lengthToCell = lengthFromCell.Offset(1, 0)

' Delete contents of "length" cells
lengthFromCell.value = ""
lengthToCell.value = ""
    
    If Target.value = "A" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="1, 2, 3"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    ElseIf Target.value = "B" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="4, 5, 6"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Else
'here either delete the validation or at least set it to 0 or ""
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="0, 0, 0"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

"Target" is the target from `Worksheet_Change` which is of type `Range`. So it is the merged cell in which my dropdown list with values "A and B" are in.

[image: picture of cells]

The main problem is that my code doesn't recognice the deletion of the value "A" in merged cells, but in single cells it does.

Comment: Please, try `If Target.value = "" then`

Comment: FYI you can remove a bunch of repetition from your code by creating a separate "AddValidation" sub and passing in `Target.Offset(0 ,1)` and the value for `Formula1`

Comment: @FaneDuru ```If Target.value = ""``` also does nothing. If I have my Target in a single cell, It works, but not with the merged cells. The same happens with ```IsEmpty(Target)```

Comment: I am afraid that a "Target **cell**" means something different. When you talk about `Target` you talk about a `Range`. Anyhow, I cannot understand what you mean, only reading your question. I suppose that editing the question and placing two pictures (existing and after) we will maybe understand what you try saying...

Comment: @FaneDuru I edited it. I hope its better now.

Comment: @TimWilliams also ErrorTitle and ErrorMessage are different. I don't know if it is worth it. But thanks for the proposal.

Comment: Do you want saying that `Target` in the picture should be "G4:G5"? If so, what "validation of the other cell" does mean? Another "H4:H5" merged cell?

Comment: @FaneDuru No. Target is "F4:F5". In this merged cell I delete the Value "A". I want my code to recognice the deletion. Something like ```If Target.value = "" Then``` or ```IsEmpty(Target)```. But this does not work with merged cells.

Comment: Do you clean the merged cells range **content**, or unmerge cells, too? Now, is "G4:G5" merged, too, or as it looks in the picture: Only "G4"?

Comment: No, I just press "Del". But the merged cells do not count as empty it seems. not for Target.value = "" nor for IsEmpty()

Comment: You did not answer the question regarding "the other cell"...

Comment: Should be self explanatory from my code. It's the ```Target.Offset(0,1)```
So "the other cell" does mean "G4" where I change the validation based on the conditions in cells "H4:H5". But those cells are not really of interest for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function isMergeEmpty(rng As Range) As Boolean
   Dim x As String
   On Error Resume Next
      x = rng.value
      If err.Number <> 0 Then
            isMergeEmpty = True
      End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

It can be called from the event in this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If isMergeEmpty(Target) Then 
        'do here what you need...
        MsgBox "Empty merge cell..."
    End if
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next full solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim myList As Object
Set myList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
myList.Add "Einseitig", 1
myList.Add "Doppelseitig", 2
myList.Add "Halbzylinder", 3

Dim lengthFromCell As range
Dim lengthToCell As range

' only execute when on column F and no more of one cell (IF Target is NOT merged):
If Target.Column <> 6 Or (Target.Cells.Count > 1 And Target.MergeCells = False) Then Exit Sub

Set lengthFromCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
Set lengthToCell = lengthFromCell.Offset(1, 0)
Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoid the event running three times
                                 'it will also be triggered for each of the following lines:
' Delete contents of "length" cells
lengthFromCell.value = ""
lengthToCell.value = ""
 
    If isMergeEmpty(Target) Then 'it should be first, in order to avoid `Target.value` which returns an error for an empty merged range
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="0, 0, 0"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Werte ausserhalb Bereich"
            .ErrorMessage = "Einseitig bla blub"
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    ElseIf Target.value = "Einseitig" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="1, 2, 3"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Werte ausserhalb Bereich"
            .ErrorMessage = "Einseitig bla blub"
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    ElseIf Target.value = "Doppelseitig" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="4, 5, 6"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Werte ausserhalb Bereich"
            .ErrorMessage = "Einseitig bla blub"
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    ElseIf Target.value = "Halbzylinder" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="7, 8, 9"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Werte ausserhalb Bereich"
            .ErrorMessage = "Einseitig bla blub"
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Function isMergeEmpty(rng As range) As Boolean
   Dim x As String
   On Error Resume Next
      x = rng.value
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            isMergeEmpty = True
      End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Now, the main problem of our code as it was consisted in the way it was exited, in case of more then one cell. VBA has a peculiar behavior when treats a merged range **having a value** and **an empty such merged range*, in terms of `Cells.Count` property. You must know that `TargetCells.Count` returns 1 if it refers a merged range **having a value** and **the number of cells in the `mergeArea` if it is empty. That's why the need to add `Or (Target.Cells.Count > 1 And Target.MergeCells = False)`. To exclude from exiting cases of empty merged `Target`. Your code, as it was, **exited on this line and the supplied function was never called**.

Then, in order to avoid `Target.Value = ...`, which returns an error in case of an empty merged `Target` the checking for an empty `Target` must be first.

I also optimized the code in order to avoid the event to be triggered three times, instead of one.

If something still unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. I alo commented the specific lines inside the code...

**Second Edit**:

I thought that you created an unmerged example only to show the different behavior against the merged one. But if you need the code to also work in such a case, another condition must be add at the end. Then, the code cam become more compact as the next one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
 Dim myList As Object: Set myList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 myList.Add "Einseitig", 1: myList.Add "Doppelseitig", 2: myList.Add "Halbzylinder", 3

 Dim lengthFromCell As range, lengthToCell As range, strFormula As String

' only execute when on column F and Target.CellsCount =1 (excluding the merged Target):
If Target.Column <> 6 Or (Target.Cells.Count > 1 And Target.MergeCells = False) Then Exit Sub

Set lengthFromCell = Target.Offset(0, 1): Set lengthToCell = lengthFromCell.Offset(1, 0)

Application.EnableEvents = False
' Delete contents of "length" cells
lengthFromCell.value = "": lengthToCell.value = ""
 
    If isMergeEmpty(Target) Then
        strFormula = "0, 0, 0"
    ElseIf Target.value = "Einseitig" Then
        strFormula = "1, 2, 3"
    ElseIf Target.value = "Doppelseitig" Then
        strFormula = "4, 5, 6"
    ElseIf Target.value = "Halbzylinder" Then
        strFormula = "7, 8, 9"
    ElseIf Target.value = "" Then 'for the case of not merged Target:
        strFormula = "0, 0, 0"
    End If
    If strFormula <> "" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:=strFormula
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Werte ausserhalb Bereich"
            .ErrorMessage = "Einseitig bla blub"
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I did. On deleting the cells content, the functions Err.Number always returns 0. So the function always returns FALSE.

Comment: It does not even trigger the function on deleting directly in the cell. Even if I press enter after the deletion it does not trigger. If I delete the value in the Formula area above my table, then pressing enter, it triggers. So it seems that ```Worksheet_Change()``` does not recognice the deletion if it is performed with the "Del" key directly in the table. This only applies to merged cells!

Comment: @omnomnom I cannot get you... I cannot imagine how you used it. When the code try to 'extract` the value of an empty merged group of cells (`x = rng.value`), it returns an error, what you were complaining of. This error is caught by `If err.Number <> 0 Then`. What you say about `Worksheet_Change()` no make any sense, neither... It behaves exactly the opposite:  Changing a formula result is not triggered by `Change` event. It is triggered only by `Calculate` event. If not something confidential in your workbook, if you send it to me, when I will have some time, I can try understanding.

Comment: I sent it to you. Maybe my workbook is broken or something.
I also tried it with ```If Not Intersect() Is Nothing``` but with no success. It just seems that deleting on merged cells the change event is not triggered.

Comment: I of course testet it with your function but I progressed testing myself. The pseudo function is a residue of my tests with If Not Intersect() Is Nothing..
I think I should test it in a fresh workbook then.

Comment: @omnomnom You should tell me that you do  not use the function and what problem you have! Testing without feedback, means nothing! A fresh workbook will not bring anything good. Your event has a problem which must  be corrected. I will do it when I will have some time. If you want trying, I do not have a problem with that.

Comment: @omnomnom Please test the solution I posted after editing the answer and send some feedback. I will be driving in the next hour and only can **see** your comments.

Comment: Ok. Now this works actually. Was it the deactivation of the events or just because its the first If statement now? Take your time to answer.

Comment: Please, look to rhe line exiting the event, if Target.count 》1... I will explain in details when I will be back in my office.

Comment: Please, test the edited answer. The **second Edit** too and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue, except I do not have Merged cells with Validation code.
To do the check in my Sheet.Change Event, I do this (pseudo) code:

```
        If IsArray(Target.Value) Then      ' Detect if multiple rows are Pasted/Deleted
            ' Do stuff for multiple cells
        Else
            ' Do stuff for single cells
        End If
```

or this one, which takes into consideration if an 'Area' is being changed:

```
        If Selection.Rows.Count * Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            ' Do stuff for multiple cells (rows and or columns)
        Else
            ' Do stuff for single cells
        End If
        'courtesy: @comintern via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199529/detect-on-worksheet-change-if-user-is-deleting
```

Hope it helps, at least someone out there...